# Generating id for tr datatable JSF

Tags: jsf, datatable

Is it possible to progrmmatically generate id for the `<tr>` in datatable?

Comment: yes. But unless you share more details, we can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the renderer associated with `UIData` component.

It's only fairly a lot of work and I don't have the impression that you're skilled enough to do that. I think it's better to elaborate more about the problem / functional requirement for which you thought that this is *the* solution, so that we can suggest better (more correct) solutions for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the expand/contract functionality of table rows in JSF using core faces implementation. As Balus mentioned in one of my earlier thread this is not straight forward to achieve in core faces implementation. So, i thought of using HTML + JQUERY to achieve the functionality. I am calling the row with +/- gif as parent row  and the rows that are to be expanded and contracted are its child rows. To make parent aware of which child it needs to show or hide, I am making use of jquery and assigning row id to each <tr>.

Comment: In continuation to my earlier comment above

if the parent row-id="row1234", then, the child row will have row-id="row1234-child". here is the code, you would require JQuery library to run this.

Jquery code:
============

<script src="jquery.js"></script><script>$(document).ready(function(){$('.expand').click(function() {if( $(this).hasClass('.hidden') ){$(this).attr("src", "plus.gif");}else{$(this).attr("src", "subtract1.gif");}$(this).toggleClass('hidden');$(this).parent().parent().siblings('#'+$(this).parent().parent().attr('id')+'-child').toggle();});});</script>

Comment: Here is the HTML code
=====================
<TR class="parent" id="row123" style="cursor: pointer; " title="Click to expand/collapse"><TD>123</TD><TD colspan="2"><img class="expand" src="plus.gif"/>ABC</TD><TD>100</TD></TR><TR ID="row123-child" style="display: none; "><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD>2007-01-02</TD><TD>A short description</TD><TD>15</TD></TR><TR ID="row123-child" style="display: none; "><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD>2007-02-03</TD><TD>Another description</TD><TD>45</TD></TR><TR ID="row123-child" style="display: none; "><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD>2007-03-04</TD><TD>More Stuff</TD><TD>40</TD></TR>

Comment: Better edit your question with udpated information instead of posting it as comment(s). It's now one and all unreadability.

Comment: Reframed the question and posted it. You can view it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142341/generate-id-for-row-in-jsf-datatable. 

Thanks for taking time out and replying to my queries. Appreciate the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me.

```
$('[id^='+tab+'][id$='+componentId+']').each(function(){
        if(!($(this).is(":checked"))) {
                $(this).parent().parent().hide();
        }
    });
```

I am hiding the rows for which checkbox is not selected.