# Generate id for row in JSF datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, row

I am trying to achieve the expand/contract functionality of table rows in JSF using core faces implementation. As answered in one of my earlier thread this is not straight forward to achieve in core faces implementation. So, I thought of using HTML + jQuery to achieve the functionality. I am calling the row with +/- gif as parent row and the rows that are to be expanded and contracted are its child rows. To make parent row aware of which child it needs to show or hide, I am making use of jquery and assigning row id to each `<tr>`. If the parent `row-id="row1234"`, then the child row will have `row-id="row1234-child"`.

Below is the Jquery Script and HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>
   <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.expand').click(function() {
     if( $(this).hasClass('.hidden') )
     {
                        $(this).attr("src", "plus.gif");
                    }
                else 
                {

                        $(this).attr("src", "subtract1.gif");
                    }

                $(this).toggleClass('hidden');

           $(this).parent().parent().siblings('#'+$(this).parent().parent().attr('id')+'-child').toggle();     

     });

      });
    </script>

    <style>
     .hover {background-color:#00f; color: #fff;}
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <thead>
      <tr><th>Rolling </th><th>transaction</th></tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <TR class="parent" id="row123" style="cursor: pointer; " title="Click to expand/collapse">
  <TD>123</TD>
  <TD colspan="2"><img 
  class="expand" src="plus.gif"/>ABC</TD>
  <TD>100</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR ID="row123-child" style="display: none; ">
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
  <TD>2007-01-02</TD>
  <TD>A short description</TD>
  <TD>15</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR ID="row123-child" style="display: none; ">
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
  <TD>2007-02-03</TD>
  <TD>Another description</TD>
  <TD>45</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR ID="row123-child" style="display: none; ">
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
  <TD>2007-03-04</TD>
  <TD>More Stuff</TD>
  <TD>40</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR class="parent" id="row2345" style="cursor: pointer; " title="Click to expand/collapse">
  <TD>234</TD>
  <TD colspan="2"><img class="expand" src="plus.gif"/>DEF</TD>
  <TD>100</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR ID="row2345-child" style="display: none; ">
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
  <TD>2007-01-02</TD>
  <TD>A short description</TD>
  <TD>15</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR ID="row2345-child" style="display: none; ">
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
  <TD>2007-02-03</TD>
  <TD>Another description</TD>
  <TD>45</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR ID="row2345-child" style="display: none; ">
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
  <TD>2007-03-04</TD>
  <TD>More Stuff</TD>
  <TD>40</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR class="parent" id="row3456" style="cursor: pointer; " title="Click to expand/collapse">
  <TD>345</TD>
  <TD colspan="2">HIJ</TD>
  <TD>100</TD>
 </TR>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </body
  </html>
```

So, I was wondering whether I can generate row id for datatable or if there is a better solution for it.

Comment: Big question: what do you need it for? As you're attempting to generate it at the client side, you apparently only need it at the client side. There are certainly better client-side ways to solve the problem for which you *thought* that *this* was *the* solution. In short: just elaborate the functional requirement instead of asking how to achieve a solution (which may not be the right solution after all).

Comment: BTW: to format code, select the code and press the `010101` button in editor toolbar or `Ctrl+K`. Please also try to not mix tabs/spaces and try to indent **consistently** (e.g. 4 or 2 spaces). In decent IDE's/editors you can configure this in the settings.

Comment: @Nrusingha - note that, by the HTML specification, element IDs must be unique - http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2